# how to validate the Textbox allows only first character Capital latter in c#.net?

Tags: c#-4.0, textbox, validating-event

I have a task, my textbox  accepts only first character capital lettr and remaing characters normal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use KeyPress event of textbox:

```
    private void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt.Text != "" && !Char.IsUpper(txt.Text, 0))
        {
            txt.Text = Char.ToUpper(txt.Text[0]) + txt.Text.Substring(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply but its working reverse what is my requirement,my requirerment is first character should be capital letter